# How to compute laplacian of a field?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to compute the laplacian of a 2d field **A** using *scipy.ndimage.convolve*.

```
stencil = numpy.array([[0, 1, 0],[1, -4, 1], [0, 1, 0]])
scipy.ndimage.convolve(A, stencil, mode='wrap')
```

This doesn't seem to give me the right answer though. Any ideas where I'm going wrong, or are there better ways of computing the laplacian in numpy?

Comment: how does it seem not right ? do you have an example image to compare to ?

Comment: I'm testing this out on a gaussian in 2d. So I have an array where I've evaluated the laplacian of the gaussian analytically, and then I try my numerical laplacian on the gaussian itself. When I take the difference between the two the results are not close to 0.

Comment: i seem to remember that a convolution with a laplace kernel is only an approximation of a laplace transform...

Comment: By laplacian I mean: d^2(phi)/dx^2 + d^2(phi)/dy^2. The stencil I used is supposed to be a finite difference approximation to the laplacian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got another idea: did you take into account that your stencil, in order to approximate the Laplacian, should be divided by step**2, where step is the step size of your grid?  Only then can you compare the ndimage.convolve result with the analytical result.

In fact, with a Gaussian, I obtain results that indicate that ndimage.convolve works quite well:

```
from scipy import ndimage

stencil = numpy.array([[0, 1, 0],[1, -4, 1], [0, 1, 0]])
x = linspace(-10, 10, 100)
y = linspace(-10, 10, 100)
xx, yy = meshgrid(x, y)
image = exp(-xx**2-yy**2)  # Standard deviation in x or y: 1/sqrt(2)

laplaced = ndimage.convolve(image, stencil)/(x[1]-x[0])**2  # stencil from original post
expected_result = -4*image + 8*(xx**2+yy**2)*image  # Very close to laplaced, in most points!
```

Comment: I did actually take that into account when I worked with the result matrix. I think the problem I was seeing was that the grid I was using was too small.

Answer (score 5):

5 years ago I wonder anyone still cares...

I think it's because the convolution method is just an approximation, the stencil is basically approximating the 2nd order derivative by finite discrete differentiation. The smaller the increment, the closer the numerical approximation will be.

I've done some tests, based on others' information. And below is the code and a result plot:

```
import numpy
import scipy.ndimage.filters as filters
import scipy.signal as signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


stencil=numpy.array([[0,1,0],[1,-4,1],[0,1,0]])

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(10,10),dpi=100)

for ii,jj in enumerate([10,100,1000,10000]):

    x=numpy.linspace(-5,5,jj)
    xx,yy=numpy.meshgrid(x,x)
    step=x[1]-x[0]

    image=numpy.exp(-xx**2-yy**2)

    lap1=filters.laplace(image)/step**2
    #lap2=filters.convolve(image,stencil,mode='wrap')/step**2
    #lap3=signal.convolve2d(image,stencil,mode='same')/step**2
    lap4=4*image*(xx**2+yy**2)-4*image

    ax=fig.add_subplot(2,2,ii+1)
    img=ax.imshow(lap1-lap4)
    ax.set_title('stencil - analytical (dx=%.4f)' %step)
    plt.colorbar(img)

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

The `filters.laplace()`, `filters.convolve()` and `signal.convolve2d()` all give very close results (in fact if you look into the source code of filters.laplace(), it is doing essentially the same thing as convolving a stencil kernel), so I include only the `filters.laplace()` one.
Note that all of the above didn't divide by the square of step.

The plot shows that the smaller the increment step, the closer to analytical solution (which is `4z(x^2+y^2)-4z`).

Comment: a useful demonstration thank you. This makes it clear that the step is not included in the function

Answer (score 1):

did you try another laplace convolution kernel, like `[[1,1,1][1,-8,1][1,1,1]]` ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your example, and it does work with the latest SciPy on my machine.

I would suggest that you plot `image-ndimage.convolve(…)` in order to see how the convolution changes your image.

Example:

```
image = vstack(arange(-10, 10)**2 for _ in range(20))
ndimage.convolve(image, stencil, mode='wrap')
```

yields

```
array([[-38,   2,   2,   2,   2,   2,   2,   2,   2,   2,   2,   2,   2,...)
```

which is quite correct (the second order derivative of x**2 being 2)—except for the left border.

Comment: I get the same result, and in 1d this works for the gaussian but the 2d gaussian still doesn't work for me.